# Some help with the question: for wich values of $a$ and $m$ does $ax = 1$ has solution in $Z_{m}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I find this exercise in the book Linear Algebra, a modern introduction by David Poole, fourth edition, it was the last one of the exercise section 1.1 about vectors (kind of odd because  of the topic, in my opinion).

Now, I have the answer, but I was wondering if there is some easier —or vector (?)— way to do it, because I use a theorem —not presented in the book— that I'm not able to prove by myself.
Here my "proof":

$ax = 1$ in $Z_{m}$

if and only if a multiple of $a$ is exactly one unit more than a multiple of $m$, that is there exist integers $k$ and $q$  such that

$ak = mq + 1$

$ak - mq = 1$

But thanks to the [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) —the theorem I mentioned early— we know that the integers of the form $az + mt$ are exactly the multiples of the greatest common divisor (g.c.d.) of $a$ and $m$. That means $k$ and $q$ exist if and only if the g.c.d of $a$, $m$ is 1, that is, $a$ and $m$ are coprime integers.

What do you think about this argument? Do you know a more "elementary" proof? Please share your opinion.

Comment: That's a good proof. Bezout's Identity is necessary for this result, as far as I am aware, so I doubt there is a proof which is far simpler. You should prove Bezout's identity yourself though (it's an application of the pigeonhole principle on the possible moduli)

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment @RushabhMehta I was in doubt because this is an exercise of a linear algebra book, and number theory was not a prerequisite, also, exercises in this type of books are not so complicated —I mean prove a theorem as intermediate step of the solution is not something you expect I guess—.

Comment: That's the standard Bezout-based proof - by far the most common proof - see the linked dupe.

Comment: For proofs using the Pigeonhole Principle see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978596/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870360/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61009/242).

Comment: We can also derive Bezout from [Lagrange's theorem on groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), e.g. see the links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151530/242), and see Samuel's paper cited there.